# Matrix solving using Casio fx-991ES plus

Tags: matrices

```
24/L  5     0
9     4L    8
8     5     5L
```

I want to calculate inverse of this matrix using calculator.
But it doesn't allow me to enter a Constant value L in the matrix. Is there any way to solve these types of matrices using Calculator (Casio fx-991ES PLUS)?

Comment: To find inverse generally for any $L$